# Adjust fan speed on ATI graphics card in OS X?

Tags: gpu

I just got an Apple 4870 and am using it with OS X fine. However it is soooo noisy.

Are there any software tools or firmware mods I can do to change the fan speed at various temperature thresholds?

Answer (score 2):

Solved: Edited and reflashed the rom from this guide:

http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=227787

Worked an absolute treat